# I cannot execute ShellExecute from javascript to run a Windows Form with parameters

Tags: javascript, c#

is it really possible to run an application installed on a users machine with parameters using an activex control. I can successfully run the application in this form:

```
$('#ejecutarActivo').click(function () {
                var Comando = $('#Comando').val();
                if (Comando.trim() != "") {
                    try {
                        var objShell = new window.ActiveXObject("shell.application");
                        objShell.ShellExecute('C:\\Users\\Jerry\\Documents\\visual studio 2012\\Projects\\PruebaComandos\\PruebaComandos\\bin\\Debug\\PruebaComandos.exe', '', '', 'open',1);
                    }
                    catch (e) {
                        alert('Active opciones de seguridad y utilice el navegador Internet Explorer');
                    }
                }
            });
```

However I don't seem to be able to run it with parameters. I really need to run it that way and I'm able to run it with the parameters from the command line, but I've tried almost every combination of single and double quotes, and also simply putting the variable name (e.g. "Comando") in the invocation but everytime I put something inside the parameter section, (which according to Microsoft documentation [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg537745(v=vs.85).aspx) is the second parameter to ShellExecute) the application starts in my computer but nothing is displayed on the screen (I mean, I see the application is running in the Task Manager but something goes wrong and nothing displays).
I need to check also the application to see if something is going wrong in the windows form. But I would like to know what's wrong in the way I'm invoking the activex.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, it wasn't a problem with ShellExecute javascript method. Actually, oops!, it was a problem with my Windows Form, I guess I will  better gain a better understanding of Serial Ports before I ask. 
I left the javascript like so:

```
$('#ejecutarActivo').click(function () {

                var Comando = $('#Comando').val();
                if (Comando.trim() != "") {
                    try {
                        var objShell = new window.ActiveXObject("shell.application");
                        if (Comando.indexOf('"') != -1) {
                            Comando = Comando.replace(/"+/g, '"""');
                        }
                        objShell.ShellExecute('C:\\Users\\Jerry\\Documents\\visual studio 2012\\Projects\\PruebaComandos\\PruebaComandos\\bin\\Debug\\PruebaComandos.exe', Comando , '', 'open', 1);
                    }
                    catch (e) {
                        alert('Active opciones de seguridad y utilice el navegador Internet Explorer');
                    }
                }
            });
```

And the code of the Windows Form goes like so: (It was a problem related to the port not closing before another invocation, which crashed the application. It's surprisingly simple)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;

namespace PruebaComandos
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SerialPort Puerto = new SerialPort();
        string buffer = String.Empty;
        Thread DemoThread;
        byte[] Existen;
        public Form1(string argumento)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Puerto.PortName = "Com4";
            Puerto.BaudRate = 9600;
            this.textoComandoLinea.Text = argumento;
            Puerto.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
            CloseSerial();
            OpenSerial();
            Puerto.Write(argumento + "\r\n");
           }
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Puerto.PortName = "Com4";
            Puerto.BaudRate = 9600;
            Puerto.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
            CloseSerial();
            OpenSerial();
            Puerto.Write("Inicio");
        }

        private void botonSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string Input = textoComandoLinea.Text;
            OpenSerial();
            Puerto.Write(Input);
        }

        void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            switch (e.EventType)
            {
                case SerialData.Chars:
                    buffer += sp.ReadExisting();
                    this.DemoThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadProcSafe));
                    this.DemoThread.Start();
                    break;
                case SerialData.Eof:
                    CloseSerial();
                    break;
            }


        }



        void OpenSerial()
        {
            if (!Puerto.IsOpen)
            {
                Puerto.Open();
            }
        }

        void CloseSerial()
        {
            if (Puerto.IsOpen)
            {
                Puerto.Close();
            }
        }

        private void ThreadProcSafe()
        {
            this.SetText(buffer);
            //CloseSerial();
        }

        delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);

        private void SetText(string text)
        {
            if (this.textoRecibido.InvokeRequired)
            {
                SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
                this.BeginInvoke(d, new object[] { text });
            }
            else
            {
                if (text.EndsWith("\r\n"))
                {
                    this.textoRecibido.Text = text;
                    if (MessageBox.Show(this, text, "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, (MessageBoxOptions)0x40000) == DialogResult.Yes)
                    {
                        Application.Exit();
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        }
    }
}
```

Anyway, the question was dumb enough to be closed in a day, I only post my code in case it helps someone. Goodbye.